# Capillary rise experiment and obtainable information about the porous medium

Tags: geophysics, hydrology, measurements

I have access to rock core(s) and vacuum saturation chambers as seen in the image below.

[image]

I can dry the rock core using an oven, measure its geometry and mass.  I can place it into the vacuum saturation chamber and allow the liquid to spontaneously imbibe (or wick) its way up and through the rock.  What, if any, are the various measurement(s) and testing procedure(s) I can perform with regards to this process that would provide me information about the rock?  For example, pore-throat size, tortuosity, pore-size distribution, porosity, permeability, etcetera.

Assume I can make all sorts of measurements.  For example, I could measure the height of the free-liquid surface that is allowed into the vacuum saturation chamber, the height of the imbibed liquid as a function of time, the vacuum pressure as a function of time (or hold it constant), etcetera.

Comment: This question is rather broad, no?

Comment: I would recommend that you clarify with the purpose of your tests or at least a more specific field of study. For example, are you looking at flow through porous media, stress and strength in soil columns, etc. I would assume that you have some purpose for collecting these samples and hooking them up in the lab?